# Is there a limitation to vote up a specific users (s)?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes, rate-limiting, rules

I need to know, Is there a kind of limitation to vote up a specific users (s)? Is it against the Stack Overflow rules to vote up some groups of users? If it is true, what is the punishments for this kind of activity?

Comment: You should only vote on **content** not users... *ever*. Voting for specific users or user groups is not advised and liable to be treated as "vote rigging" or *cheating*. Simply...DON'T!

Comment: i know this is a not good way to voting, i want to know what are the rules ?!!!!

Answer (score 11):

> Is it against the Stack Overflow rules to vote up some groups of users?

**YES**, its against the rules of SO..

> What is the punishments for this kind of activity?

Your account will be suspend for rule violations.

Check this post [“This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities.”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/this-account-is-temporarily-suspended-for-voting-irregularities)

Read here https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/